# Popularity Trends report not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2016, searchserviceapplication, popularity-trends

We have to recreate our search service application due to some errors in previous one. But since the change **popularity trends** report for files started coming empty. We tried to get it through script. We are able to get reports for site. But for files no luck.
Is there any way to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue existing in every file or a few files?

Try  to troubleshoot this issue as following:

1. Make sure the search service application is actively crawling the content, and the files are crawled.
2. Please check if the following timer jobs is running, then re-run them and check again:

   - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import
   - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing
3. Using PowerShell command below to check if the relevant Instantiating usage receivers are missing:

   $aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"}

   $aud | fl

   $prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}

   $prud | fl

And there are some similar link for your reference:

[SharePoint 2016 Popularity Trends and Usage data return no results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51478.sharepoint-2016-popularity-trends-and-usage-data-return-no-results.aspx)

[SharePoint 2016 popularity trends excel report not showing the data (zero hit count) for few page items](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d59f55cb-dead-4325-ad9c-9e9101bfa07d/sharepoint-2016-popularity-trends-excel-report-not-showing-the-data-zero-hit-count-for-few-page?forum=SP2016)

Comment: Here are my observations : 1) SSA is crawling contents properly. 2) Both the jobs are running properly. 3) Both the receivers are enabled. 
Still no result in popularity trends.